# html unwanted line below the video

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm  trying to add a video banner to my wordpress website by adding a html widget to the top bar. It's working fine, but there is a line I can't hide. Also couldn't find it in the inspect menu.
The code and some pictures about it:

```
<div class="top-bar top-bar-align-right">
<video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto"><source src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph1221/f/EchoPark_1920x800_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</div>
```

```
#video{ 
    object-fit: cover !important;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
.inside-top-bar{ 
    padding: 0px;
    }
.top-bar-align-right .inside-top-bar>.widget:nth-child(odd), 
.top-bar-align-center .inside-top-bar .widget:not(:first-child){ 
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .top-bar .widget{
        margin: 0 !important;
        }
    }
#video{ 
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    }
```

the images:
As you can see, there is a light gray line between the black menu and the video:
https://i.postimg.cc/9fk4HgJD/image.png
the inspect menu:
https://i.postimg.cc/8c4NNjNZ/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<video>` element is default `{ display: inline }`, make it `video { display: block }` (or `inline-block`) and it will probably work for you!

Snippet: the space below video 1 is what your are experiencing (no space below 2 and 3)

**UPDATE** added OP code to show that the offered solution works: no space between OP video and video 1. However, without use of `.video-block` it does show some space.

Something else on the 'Live page' must cause the spacing...

```css
div          { background: red }
.video-block { display: block }

#video{ 
    object-fit: cover !important;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
}
.inside-top-bar{ 
    padding: 0px;
}
.top-bar-align-right .inside-top-bar>.widget:nth-child(odd), 
.top-bar-align-center .inside-top-bar .widget:not(:first-child){ 
    margin-left: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .top-bar .widget{
        margin: 0 !important;
    }
}
#video{ 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar top-bar-align-right">
    <video class="video-block" id="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="muted" preload="auto">
        <source src="https://www.lacity.org/sites/g/files/wph1221/f/EchoPark_1920x800_loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <video class="video-block" width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <video class="video-block" width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried both but in my case it's still there: https://i.postimg.cc/TwSVdqJP/image.png

Comment: @admin, something else must be wrong, as with your code added in the snippet and my `.video-block { display: block }` it still works as advertised.

Comment: Yes, it will be something else. I temporary solved it by setting the background color of the .top-bar to the same color as the nav. It's not that important at the moment, but I'll take a look at it later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, comment here if you want me to get back at the issue.